# Excel VBA - Cell Referencing in If statement inside a For Loop

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to use if statement inside a For loop and it is giving Runtime Error 1004 “Application-defined or Object-defined error”. I am using the below code(I have commented where the error occurs). I think it is because of cell referencing that I've used for the for loop.
Please help.

```
Sub ifcheck()

Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 5
Cells(3, 2).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(AND(Availability!R3C2>=Interviewers!R[i]C[1],Availability!R3C1>=Interviewers!R[i]C[3]),Interviewers!R4C2,"""")"
 '>>>The above line shows as error 1004 - “Application-defined or Object-defined error”
Range("B3").Select
Next i
End Sub
```

Thanks,
Jay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try splicing `i` into the formula with basic string concatenation.

```
Dim i As long
For i = 1 To 5
    Cells(2+i, 2).FormulaR1C1 = _
      "=IF(AND(Availability!R3C2>=Interviewers!R[" & i & "]C[1], Availability!R3C1>=Interviewers!R[" & i & "]C[3]), Interviewers!R4C2, text(,))"
Next i
```

Since cells(3, 2) is B3, I don't know what you are intending to do for successive loops. I've moved down one row for each loop.